# GSON Library parse JSON UTF-8 not properly, replace accent by "?"

Tags: java, php, json, utf-8, gson

I'm try to develop a Java application with GSON library to parse JSON (from PHP file (encoding in UTF-8) -> json_encode)

My php source :

```
<?php
$base = mysql_connect ('****', '*****', '*****');  
mysql_select_db ('*****', $base) ; 
$req = mysql_query("SELECT ***, ****, ***, ****, **** from *****");

function jsonRemoveUnicodeSequences($struct) {
   return preg_replace("/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/e", "iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8',pack('V', hexdec('U$1')))",               json_encode($struct));
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($req)) {
    $output[] = $row;
}

print(jsonRemoveUnicodeSequences($output));    
mysql_free_result ($req);    
?>
```

JSON string is properly displayed with accent in in my web browser.

My Java source :

```
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("**************");
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection(); 

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();            
            String line = null;  

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                System.out.println("JSON data issu du PHP : "+ line + "\n");
                Gson gson = new Gson();

                Type type = new TypeToken<List<AlertTable>>(){}.getType();
                ArrayList<AlertTable> bddListJson = gson.fromJson(line, type);              
                bddList = (ArrayList<AlertTable>) bddListJson.clone();                   
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                //
            }
        }   

        System.out.println(bddList.get(1).getTypeAlert());
        System.out.println(bddList.get(1).getLigne());
        System.out.println(bddList.get(1).getSens());
        System.out.println(bddList.get(1).getStation());
        System.out.println(bddList.get(1).getTimeAlert());
```

And in console, character with accent is replaced by "?".

Any idea ?

Comment: Just to be sure, can you exclude problem with the console? Have you tried to print the characters to a file encoded in some Unicode scheme, like UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that your code may fail on some systems because MySQL uses a *connection charset* to move text between the client and the server. You should issue a raw query like `SET NAMES <charset>` to set the encoding of the input data available in your script.

Now, assuming there's no transcoding issue (because your columns only store ASCII characters and all charset involved are ASCII-compatible), I wrote the following code to replace `\u0000` escape sequences with UTF8-encoded strings:

```
<?php

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($req)) {
  $out[] = preg_replace_callback("/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/i", "unescape", $row);
}

// On PHP 5.4+ use json_encode($out, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
echo json_encode($out);

/* Accept the matcher array
 * return the UTF-8 encoded string
 */
function unescape($match) {
  return call_user_func_array('pack', get_pack_args(hexdec($match[1])));
}

function get_pack_args($cp) {
  if ($cp < 0x80) return array('C1', $cp);

  if ($cp < 0x0800) {
    $length = 2;
  } else if ($cp < 0x010000) {
    $length = 3;
  } else {
    $length = 4;
  }

  $args[0] = "C{$length}";

  // lead byte
  $args[1] = (0xFE << (7 - $length)) | ($cp >> (6 * ($length - 1)));

  // continuation bytes
  for ($l = 0; $l < ($length - 1); $l++) {
    $args[$length - $l] = 0x80 | (($cp >> (6 * $l)) & 0x3F);
  }

  // stupid PHP...
  ksort($args);
  return $args;
}
```

You should test the code deeply, however it's a good starting point. For displaying in a browser, you should specify the encoding with a HTTP header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
```

Note that `json_encode()` escapes unicode sequences on its part by default. This is inefficient, so you may want to use the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag, or choose another JSON library for encoding.

At this point the server part should be ok, and you can test it with your browser. If it works, but the Java program can't still show the right characters on the console, it may be a problem with the console itself, or even with the font used by the console application. Without the actual data one can't tell, however follow my advice and print the JSON to a text file UTF8-encoded. Then open it with a text editor (specifying UTF-8 if needed) and tell what you see.

Finally, note that the usage of the `mysql` PHP extension is discouraged. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

if You set parameter of json_encode Correctly like

```
 json_encode($WhoRank,JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

no problem in encoding value and transfer data but if is not work again  you can Use **urlencode** for Encode UTF-8 Value and Decode it on Java

like this

```
urlencode('aیgfسبd');
```

output

```
a%DB%8Cgf%D8%B3%D8%A8d
```

with this output You haven't  problem in json value.

Comment: but that is only for the url in the request. the problem here is with the response, it seems.